# edit footer in html page using css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in HTML, CSS and I'm having trouble with editing the footer on my html page. I'm trying to resize the facebook and twitter icon too much smaller size (both the same size), they have them side by side in the bottom centre of the html page along with the copyright sign.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepageuni.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="homepage" content="a homepage for the survey website">
    <title> Kingston University Survey Homepage</title>
    <body>
        <img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" id="uni" alt="uni logo"/>
        <div id = "buttons">
            <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button home-button">Home</button>
            <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button contact-button">Contact Us</button>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">LogIn</a>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <img src="homepagepic.jpg" alt="homepagepic" id="middlepic" />
        <br/>
        <div id="footer">
            &copy;
            <img src="facebookpic.png" alt="facebookpic" />
            <img src="twitterpic.jpg" alt="twitterpic"/>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#middlepic {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#uni {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float:left; 
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add css rule like bellow

```css
#footer img {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px
}
```

if you wish to change size just change width and height

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to each image and set their size that way.

*HTML*

```
<div id="footer">
     &copy;
     <img class="social-badge" src="facebookpic.png" alt="facebook logo">
     <img class="social-badge" src="twitterpic.jpg" alt="twitter logo">
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.social-badge {
     width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.logos{
  width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" id="uni" alt="uni logo" />

<div id="buttons">
  <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button home-button">Home</button>
  <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button contact-button">Contact Us</button>

  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">LogIn</a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="homepagepic.jpg" alt="homepagepic" id="middlepic" />
<br/>
<div id="footer">
  &copy;
  <img class="logos" src="facebookpic.png" alt="facebookpic" />
  <img class="logos" src="twitterpic.jpg" alt="twitterpic" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an class to the img tag an add a style from css like this.

CSS:

```css
.socialimg { width: 10px; }
```

HTML:

```
<img class="socialimg" src="facebookpic.png"  alt="facebookpic">
<img class="socialimg" src="twitterpic.jpg" alt="twitterpic">
```

Comment: *ID*s should only be used once per page. Use a *class* instead.